# How do I install older version of groovy in my linux machine - groovy 1.8.6?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, java

My Linux machine has OS : Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Currently it has groovy version:

```
build@###: $  groovy -version
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/usr/share/groovy/lib/groovy-2.4.16.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Groovy Version: 2.4.16 JVM: 11.0.5 Vendor: Private Build OS: Linux
```

I want to downgrade it to 1.8.6

Please guide

Answer (score 0):

I did not find groovy 1.8.6 in the default apt repos.
Unless you find a repo that supports it, you should do it by hand.
The problem is that 1.8.6 is very old and I did not find the files even at the a[pache groovy site](https://groovy.apache.org/download.html).
Some of the jars are available [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/) e.g. you can donwload the [groovy-all jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/1.8.6/).
With that you should be able to run any compiled classes adding this to your classpath.
Set the JAVA_HOME to some proper version of java, I guess I would try a Java 6 or 7.
Otherwise recompile your sources, if you have them, with a newer version of groovy. That might need some fixing of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have java 8 installed in my system.

openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-8u232-b09-0ubuntu1~18.04.1-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)

Not sure, How do i proceed

Comment: export the JAVA_HOME to the path of where you installed java8, next export PATH= $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH, download the groovyall jar from the link I gave you. Set the CLASSPATH to include your class files and the groovy-all-1.8.6.jar and finally run your main class

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the binary: https://bintray.com/version/files/groovy/maven/groovy/1.8.6

#### Update 1

How to install:

```
$ unzip groovy-binary-1.8.6.zip
$ sudo mv ./groovy-1.8.6 /usr/share/groovy-1.8.6
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/groovy" "groovy" "/usr/share/groovy-1.8.6/bin/groovy" 186
```

Comment: It would be more useful if you could add the instructions to add the binary to the system ;-)